# How to crawl only a subfolder with Anemone

Tags: ruby, web-crawler, anemone

We can crawl a hole website with anemone (ex: `https://stackoverflow.com/`), but what if I want only focus on a certain folder (ex: https://stackoverflow.com/`questions`). How can I do this ? maybe with the "focus_crawl" method ?

Answer (score 2):

check the keep_if method may be this helps

http://danneu.com/posts/8-scraping-a-blog-with-anemone-ruby-web-crawler-and-mongodb#toc_1

try and pass the pattern as you want to crawl

also there is a gist https://gist.github.com/1149906.

NOTE: I haven't tested it but you can sure surely try.

Comment: thank you PriteshJ but I finally found the answer. I've used the method `on_pages_like` instead of `on_every_page` with the pattern like this: `on_pages_like(/http:\/\/stackoverflow.com\/questions\/.)` and it works well. thank you again